# google search result thumbnail won't change no matter what approach i follow

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, seo

i know that we can't programmatically and explicitly set an image for our google search result thumbnail. so we have to follow different approaches to get google crawlers to "notice" and use a certain image as the thumbnail to our search result.
however i've tried multiple approaches and non of them seem to work, what's even more weird is that google is showing a thumbnail of an image that doesn't exist at all on my website or in the project files, so i can't even delete it!

[image]

the app is built using vue and nuxt.js and deployed on vercel, does vercel have any methods to set up a search result thumbnail from its side?

the methods i followed to present an image to be selected as a search result thumbnail are as follows (these have been deployed for over a month!):

1- meta tags: from my nuxt config file i've set the following metatags to refer to the desired images:

```
      {
        hid: 'og:image',
        name: 'og:image',
        content: '/img/muh-logo.jpg'
      },
      {
        hid: 'twitter:image',
        name: 'twitter:image',
        content: '/img/muh-logo.jpg'
      },
      {
        name: 'thumbnail',
        content: '/img/muh-logo.jpg'
      }
```

2- include image in sitemap, also from my nuxt config file:

```
  sitemap: {
    hostname: process.env.HOST_NAME,
    routes: () => {
      const routes = [
        {
          url: '/',
          img: [
            { url: '/img/muh-logo.jpg' }
          ]
        }
      ]

      return routes
    }
  }
```

3- schema.org script (i just copied it and included my thumbnail path)

```
  <script type="application/ld+json">
    {"@context" : "http://schema.org",
      "@type" : "Organization",
      "name" : "muh",
      "url" : "https://www.muh.com",
      "logo": "/img/muh-logo.jpg" }
  </script>
```

4- PageMap (chatGPT told me about this one)

```
  <PageMap>
    <DataObject type="thumbnail">
      <Attribute name="src" value="/img/muh-logo.jpg"/>
      <Attribute name="width" value="100"/>
      <Attribute name="height" value="130"/>
    </DataObject>
  </PageMap>
```

again after all those steps, the thumbnail is just stuck to that image you see above, i don't have this image in my project and i think it was generated somehow by vercel?

am i doing something wrong in my steps? can i do something through vercel to help me resolve this issue?